# testing if intercept=0 and slope coefficient=1

Tags: simulation, prediction, model

I have an output from a relatively complex simulation model (Pred) that is trying to predict some observations (Obs).  I state that it is relatively complex because the simulation cannot be used in my questions that follow.  I only have the output from this model (Pred) and some observations that the model is attempting to predict.  That is all, just two columns of numbers to compare in various ways.  They are both continuous variables and are bounded between 0 and 1.

The ideal simulation would have Pred=Obs (so a simple regression of the two would give a perfect fit and Obs = 0 + 1*Pred).

I have already calculated Pearson correlations between Pred and Obs and tested these with the null of correlation=0.  I have also calculated root mean square deviation and mean absolute deviation and compared these to null distributions where Pred is random.

A more senior person in my group thinks we should also perform the simple linear regression I described previously.  I suppose we would then look at 95% CIs around the intercept and single slope coefficient to determine if the intervals contain 0 and 1, respectively.

However, this is "wanting" a high p-value (I suppose 0.5 for a 2-tailed test), and I am unsure whether or not there is a better way to approach this.

Any advice on this?

I can't help but think there is a way to approach this where a lower p-value would be more desirable in terms of model predictive ability.

Comment: No one can direct me to a resource?